# How to deal with Pagination when scraping

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping, pagination

A website I'm scraping for educational purposes has pagination.

My code is scraping the first page perfectly fine...

But how would I scrape

```
?page=2
?page=3
?page=4
?page=5
```

And beyond??...

Should be noted I have looked for solutions, but can't seem to find anything which definitively answers what I need to know.

Current code:

```
// @nuget: HtmlAgilityPack
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net;
using HtmlAgilityPack;


public class Program

{

    public static void Main()
    {


        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
               | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
               | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
               | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument html = web.Load("https://www.g2crowd.com/products/google-analytics/reviews");
        //  var divNodes = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='mb-2 border-bottom']");

        var divNodes = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//div[@itemprop='reviewBody']");

        if (divNodes != null)
        {
            foreach (var tag in divNodes)
            {
                string review = tag.InnerText;
                review = review.Replace("What do you like best?", "What do you like best?\n");
                review = review.Replace("What do you dislike?", "\nWhat do you dislike?\n");
                review = review.Replace("Recommendations to others considering the product", "\n\nRecommendations to others considering the product\n");
                review = review.Replace("What business problems are you solving with the product?  What benefits have you realized?", "\n\nWhat business problems are you solving with the product?  What benefits have you realized?\n");
                Console.WriteLine(review);
                Console.WriteLine("\n------------------------------- Review found. Adding to Database -------------------------------\n");
                review = review.Replace("'", "");
                review = review.Replace("\n", "<br />");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you instinctively think you would deal with it ? and you probably have your answer... There is no magic bullet here, either try for the next page, or search the page for clues to see if you can

Comment: My guess is either following the link to the next page, or somehow coding when done with page=1 > move to page=2? Pretty new to C# - very hard to put my thoughts into code. A nudge from SO has seemed to help me learn a lot in the past! Bit stumped is all!

Comment: Depending if you are making a crawler or not, then the link should be followable if there, if you are just trying to get the set then once again, just follow the link, not really much more i can add. maybe someone else can chime in

Answer (score 0):

The next link looks like this:

```
//link[@rel=next]
```

Just keep following it until it's not there anymore.

Comment: `next_page = response.xpath('//link[@rel="next"]/@href').extract_first();
                if (next_page
                yield response.follow(next_page));` This is what I have so far. Doesn't seem to work as of yet.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what `response` is there, it should be the html parser object, not the raw response if that makes sense.